# Run daemons before logging-in

Tags: wireless, services, session, init.d

I have some daemons to run once boot is finished, the main one is a Wifi AP.

My question is: how to ensure the daemon run even if I'm not logged-in ?

**EDIT** `init.d`: in spite of gøøg1ing about, I dont understand if it is called once logged or *before* ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put command in `rc.local` witch will run service. `rc.local` boot process run at the end.

```
  sudo nano /etc/rc.local

#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0

service XXXX start
```

Save end exit. Next time when you boot pc, at the end, after networking, fw, ... service `XXXX` wil be started.